# Cannot solve multi-timeframe ATR Trailing Stop

Tags: pine-script

I have tried to solve the last 3 lines of this pine script. The problem still exist, the color is in blue, no green or red as expected.

[image: 1]

```
atrTimeframe = input.timeframe(title="ATR Timeframe", defval="60")
atrPeriod = input.int(10, "ATR Period")
atrMultiplier = input.float(3, "ATR Multiplier", step=.1)

ATR = ta.atr(atrPeriod)
Stop = atrMultiplier*ATR

atrStop() =>
    var atrTrailingstop = 0.0
    atrTrailingstop := if close>atrTrailingstop[1] and close[1]>atrTrailingstop[1]
    math.max(atrTrailingstop[1], close-Stop)
    else if close<atrTrailingstop[1] and close[1]<atrTrailingstop[1]
        math.min(atrTrailingstop[1], close+Stop)
    else if close>atrTrailingstop[1]
        close-Stop 
    else 
        close+Stop

atrTrailingstop = atrStop()
var Position = 0.0
Position := if close[1]<atrTrailingstop[1] and close>atrTrailingstop[1]
    1
else if close[1]>atrTrailingstop[1] and close<atrTrailingstop[1]
    -1
else
    Position[1]

PlotColor = Position == -1 ? color.red: Position == 1 ? color.green : color.blue
[atrSecure, mtfColor] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, atrTimeframe, [atrStop(), PlotColor], gaps=barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_off)
plot(atrSecure, color=mtfColor, linewidth=input(1, "Line Width"), title="ATR Trailing Stop")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to get the `Position` from the higher timeframe and then calculate the color.
However, `Position` is a mutable variable so you need to calculate its value in a function.

Below is how you can do it:

```
f_get_pos() =>
    var Position = 0.0
    Position := if close[1]<atrTrailingstop[1] and close>atrTrailingstop[1]
        1
    else if close[1]>atrTrailingstop[1] and close<atrTrailingstop[1]
        -1
    else
        Position[1]

[atrSecure, Position] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, atrTimeframe, [atrStop(), f_get_pos()], gaps=barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_off)

PlotColor = Position == -1 ? color.red: Position == 1 ? color.green : color.blue
plot(atrSecure, color=PlotColor, linewidth=input(1, "Line Width"), title="ATR Trailing Stop")
```